# Remove visible grid of HTML Table through DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, border

I'm currently trying to remove the borders of a simple table through DOM-Code.
None of the solutions I found in the internet worked:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
... Add elements into table ...
table.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";
table.style.border = "none";
table.style.outline = "none";
table.style.cellPadding = "0";
table.style.cellSpacing = "0";
... for each cell in the table ...
    var td = ...
    td.style.cellPadding = "0";
    td.style.cellSpacing = "0";
```

Also, even if it would work, I don't like the solution, because I actually WANT to have padding and spacing on my cells, I just want to remove the visible grid. (In my case I'm using a table to "order"/"set the position" of different elements)
So how do I remove those borders, and is it possible without removing padding and spacing?

Comment: table or/and td or/and th {border:none;} eventually border:none!important;  Have you tried these ? Maybe your border is a box shadow or backgrounds ? ot enough code of yours to tell

Comment: @GCyrillus Tried these, and my only other styles for the table are "position", "top", and "width". Doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a JSFiddle?

Comment: @JoshBurgess Weirdly, there isn't any border on JSFiddle tables by default...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following attribute: table border

> 1 = cell border on
>   0= cell border off

Comment: I think the .style is getting in the way... I think you want table.border = "0"

Comment: Tried it too, border still stays... It's weird :(

Answer (score 0):

I checked all of my included files, and noticed that one external JavaScript-File set the border of all tables to 1 by default, thus causing this problem to occur.

By removing the dependency, the border also gets removed. What I don't understand, is why that "border"-line didn't get overridden by my code...